# Why my SQLite3 query takes time?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite, profiling, vfs

Context: I developed a Read-Only VFS for SQLite using the C API. The thing is what I need is both speed and small file size. I solved the size problem with a LZ4 based VFS. However I have some speed issues when I query my DB.

Specifications: 
 - I work on Linux (Ubuntu 12.10)
 - DB files are 275MB compressed and about 700MB uncompressed
 - I am doing queries on indexed fields. 
 - I evaluate the time taken for a given query after droping caches (echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/dropcaches)

Problem:
When I query the DB with the command time, I get the following output:
 real   0m5.933s
 user   0m0.124s
 sys    0m0.096s
What is surprising is the difference between user+sys and real. This is why I decided to profile, with gprof, the code I have written as well as its dependencies (sqlite3,lz4). Hereafter, you will find few lines of the gprof flat and call-graph representation. After that, I have no idea about what to look out if I want to find a solution. Mainly because I do not understand why (and where) all this time is wasted. I hope you can help me.

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 93.75      0.15     0.15     2948     0.05     0.05  LZ4_decompress_fast
  6.25      0.16     0.01    26068     0.00     0.01  sqlite3VdbeCursorMoveto
  0.00      0.16     0.00    54088     0.00     0.00  sqlite3GetVarint
  0.00      0.16     0.00    28459     0.00     0.00  sqlite3VdbeSerialGet
  0.00      0.16     0.00    23708     0.00     0.00  sqlite3VdbeMemNulTerminate
  0.00      0.16     0.00    23699     0.00     0.00  sqlite3_transfer_bindings
  0.00      0.16     0.00    11910     0.00     0.00  sqlite3DbMallocSize
  0.00      0.16     0.00    11883     0.00     0.00  sqlite3VdbeMemGrow
  0.00      0.16     0.00    11851     0.00     0.00  sqlite3VdbeMemMakeWriteable
  0.00      0.16     0.00     9480     0.00     0.00  fetchPayload
  0.00      0.16     0.00     9478     0.00     0.00  sqlite3VdbeMemRelease
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7170     0.00     0.02  btreeGetPage
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7170     0.00     0.00  pcache1Fetch
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7170     0.00     0.00  releasePage
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7170     0.00     0.02  sqlite3PagerAcquire
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7170     0.00     0.00  sqlite3PagerUnrefNotNull
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7170     0.00     0.00  sqlite3PcacheFetch
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7170     0.00     0.00  sqlite3PcacheRelease
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7169     0.00     0.00  pcache1Unpin
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7169     0.00     0.00  pcacheUnpin
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7168     0.00     0.02  getAndInitPage
  0.00      0.16     0.00     7165     0.00     0.02  moveToChild

granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) for 6.25% of 0.16 seconds

index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]    100.0    0.00    0.16                 main [1]
                0.00    0.16       1/1           sqlite3_exec <cycle 1> [5]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           openDatabase [18]
                0.00    0.00       2/3           sqlite3_vfs_find [249]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           sqlite3_crodvfs [358]
                0.00    0.00       1/14          sqlite3_vfs_register <cycle 5> [204]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           sqlite3_open_v2 [359]
-----------------------------------------------
[2]     99.9    0.00    0.16       1+198     <cycle 1 as a whole> [2]
                0.00    0.16       2             sqlite3_exec <cycle 1> [5]
                0.00    0.00       2             sqlite3InitOne <cycle 1> [27]
                0.00    0.00     124             sqlite3Parser <cycle 1> [82]
                0.00    0.00       6+4           sqlite3WalkSelect <cycle 1> [186]
                0.00    0.00       9             sqlite3ReadSchema <cycle 1> [149]
                0.00    0.00       7             sqlite3LockAndPrepare <cycle 1> [168]
                0.00    0.00       7             sqlite3Prepare <cycle 1> [171]
                0.00    0.00       7             sqlite3RunParser <cycle 1> [172]
                0.00    0.00       5             sqlite3InitCallback <cycle 1> [196]
                0.00    0.00       5             sqlite3_prepare <cycle 1> [203]
                0.00    0.00       5             sqlite3SelectPrep <cycle 1> [198]
                0.00    0.00       4             sqlite3LocateTable <cycle 1> [213]
                0.00    0.00       3             sqlite3StartTable <cycle 1> [243]
                0.00    0.00       2             selectExpander <cycle 1> [277]
                0.00    0.00       2             sqlite3Select <cycle 1> [299]
                0.00    0.00       2             sqlite3CreateIndex <cycle 1> [282]
                0.00    0.00       2             sqlite3_prepare_v2 <cycle 1> [312]
                0.00    0.00       2             resolveSelectStep <cycle 1> [275]
                0.00    0.00       2             resolveOrderGroupBy <cycle 1> [274]
                0.00    0.00       1             sqlite3Init <cycle 1> [347]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.16    2374/2374        sqlite3_step [4]
[3]     99.9    0.00    0.16    2374         sqlite3VdbeExec [3]
                0.01    0.15   26068/26068       sqlite3VdbeCursorMoveto [6]
                0.00    0.00      53/54          moveToLeftmost [17]
                0.00    0.00       2/3           sqlite3BtreeBeginTrans [20]
                0.00    0.00       1/2370        sqlite3BtreeMovetoUnpacked [16]
                0.00    0.00    2372/2372        sqlite3BtreeNext [28]
                0.00    0.00       1/2371        moveToRoot [23]
                0.00    0.00   26068/28459       sqlite3VdbeSerialGet [34]
                0.00    0.00   23699/23708       sqlite3VdbeMemNulTerminate [35]
                0.00    0.00   23699/23699       sqlite3_transfer_bindings [36]
                0.00    0.00   11851/11851       sqlite3VdbeMemMakeWriteable [39]
                0.00    0.00    7108/7109        sqlite3BtreeKeySize [49]
                0.00    0.00    4741/9480        fetchPayload [40]
                0.00    0.00    4739/4739        sqlite3VdbeMemFromBtree [55]
                0.00    0.00    4739/9478        sqlite3VdbeMemRelease [41]
                0.00    0.00    2374/2376        sqlite3VdbeMemShallowCopy [65]
                0.00    0.00    2372/2376        sqlite3VdbeCheckFk [64]
                0.00    0.00    2372/2372        sqlite3VdbeCloseStatement [66]
                0.00    0.00    2372/4742        btreeParseCellPtr [54]
                0.00    0.00    2372/4742        btreeParseCell [53]
                0.00    0.00    2370/2391        sqlite3VdbeRecordCompare [63]
                0.00    0.00    2369/2369        sqlite3VdbeIntValue [67]
                0.00    0.00     893/893         sqlite3VdbeRealValue [74]
                0.00    0.00       3/3           sqlite3VdbeFreeCursor [245]
                0.00    0.00       3/3           allocateCursor [226]
                0.00    0.00       3/3           sqlite3BtreeCursor [237]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           sqlite3VdbeHalt [152]
                0.00    0.00       1/36          sqlite3BtreeLeave [98]
                0.00    0.00       1/6           sqlite3BtreeGetMeta [185]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           sqlite3GetVarint32 [345]
```

Comment: [improve sqlite perfomance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711631/2549281)

Comment: Most of that time is not CPU but I/O.

Comment: It could depend on the size of data chunks to be decompressed. If you compress an entire column, you will have to decompress it entirely before accessing a single element into it. Therefore, it's better to cut it into smaller data blocks.